# Error in installing phpmyadmin

Tags: linux-mint, phpmyadmin

I am installing phpmyadmin in Linux Mint 19 using this command sudo apt-get install mysql-server php7.0-mysql phpmyadmin. But I am getting below error while I am trying to browsing phpmyadmin.

[image]

Comment: Could it be that whatever you use as webserver, hasn't been configured to run PHP?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille, yes.

Comment: I don't know linux-mint.  Doesn't it check dependencies when you installed phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 1):

Your apache isn't interpreting PHP code.

This can be caused by inumerous reasons. In your case, Apache is configured with *multi-processing module* that don't interpret PHP alone, this is not wrong but they should be used with PHP-FPM, and it is not your case.

The simplest method to make it work, go to the terminal and disable both **event** and **worker** apache modules:

```
sudo su -
a2dismod mpm_event mpm_worker
```

You should know what is your php module version (mine is 7.2):

```
ls /etc/apache2/mods-available
```

Then enable **prefork** and **php** extensions and restart apache:

```
sudo su -
a2enmod mpm_prefork php7.2
systemctl restart apache2
```

Done!